# Having difficulty importing functions from other files, getting traceback errors and don't understand why

Tags: python, file, import

I'm having some difficulty importing things form other files. I have the following files, with the following methods:

- choices.py `rest, go_hunting, gather_firewood, build_shelter, create_signal_fire, look_for_escape, try_to_start_fire`
- battle.py `battle, win_battle, lose_battle`
- game.py `start_adventure, welcome_screen`
- prepare.py `gather_gear`
- settings.py `create_player, formatter, die, return_to_camp, found_nothing, progress_bar, eat_food, restore`

What should happen is when you run `python game.py` the game should start by asking you for your character name. However, when I run it I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 1, in <module>
    from choices import gather_fire_wood, go_hunting, build_shelter, \
  File "C:\Users\thomas_j_perkins\bin\python\game\choices.py", line 1, in <modul
e>
    from settings import formatter, BACKPACK, SURVIVAL_TOOLS, \
  File "C:\Users\thomas_j_perkins\bin\python\game\settings.py", line 3, in <modu
le>
    from choices import rest
ImportError: cannot import name rest
```

What I've tried:

- Moving the method `rest` to the settings and changing the imports to reflect that.
- Moving all the imports into a single file
- Moving `rest` to the top of the file `choices.py`
- Putting `print` everywhere
- Running it through a debugger
- Googling the issue, I know the issue, it's not importing, Google told me that I wasn't importing the file in the right spot, or the import wasn't in that file.

Now there are a lot of files, and I've been trying to debug this for about 2 hours.

Choices.py:

```
from settings import formatter, BACKPACK, SURVIVAL_TOOLS, \
    eat_food, return_to_camp, found_nothing, \
    die, HEALTH
from random import randint, random
from battle import battle


def rest():
    print formatter()
    print "You sit down and feel kind of hungry."

    foods = ['granola bars', 'cooked meat', 'dried foods', 'raw meat']

    intersection = set(foods) & set(BACKPACK)

    if intersection:
        for food in BACKPACK:
            print "{} of {}".format(BACKPACK[food], food)

        while True:
            choice = raw_input('What would you like to eat, enter \'nothing\' to return to camp: ').lower()
            if choice in food:
                eat_food(choice)
                break
            elif choice == 'nothing':
                return_to_camp()
            else:
                print "Can't eat {}".format(choice)


def go_hunting():
    animals = ['deer', 'elk', 'fox', 'rat', 'mountain lion', 'nothing']  # Random animals to choose from.

    animal_came_across = random.choice(animals)
    print "You start walking and come to a clearing." \
          " You see something rustling in the bushes" \
          " as you stare it jumps out." \

    if animal_came_across == 'nothing':
        print "The animal turns and runs away before you can" \
              " get a good look at it.."
        found_nothing()
    else:
        print "You have come across a {}!".format(animal_came_across)
        print "You have the following to choose from:\n"
        for weapon in BACKPACK:
            print "{}".format(weapon)
        print "\n"

        while True:
            weapon = raw_input('Choose your weapon: ')
            if weapon not in BACKPACK:
                print "Can't use that, you don't have it!"
            else:
                print 'Prepare to attack your prey!'
                battle(animal_came_across, weapon, HEALTH)


def gather_fire_wood():
    print "You walk out into the woods." \
          " You start gathering some firewood."

    wood_gathered = randint(2, 10)
    SURVIVAL_TOOLS['fire wood'] = wood_gathered

    print "You have gathered {} logs.".format(wood_gathered)

    while True:
        choice = raw_input('Would you like to build a fire [Y/N]: ').lower()
        if choice == 'y':
            try_to_start_fire(wood_gathered)
            break
        elif choice == 'n':
            print "You decide to try to make a shelter."
            build_shelter()
            break
        else:
            print "Expected 'Y' or 'N' got {}, try again..".format(choice)


def build_shelter():
    print "building shelter"


def create_signal_fire():
    logs_needed = randint(5, 10)
    logs_obtained = SURVIVAL_TOOLS['fire wood']

    print "To build a signal fire you will need {} logs" \
          " You currently have {}.".format(logs_needed, SURVIVAL_TOOLS['fire wood'])

    if logs_obtained < logs_needed:
        print "You don't have enough logs to start a signal fire."
        while True:
            choice = raw_input('Would you like to gather more [Y/N]: ').lower()
            if choice == 'y':
                gather_fire_wood()
            elif choice == 'n':
                return_to_camp()
            else:
                print "Expected 'Y' or 'N' got {}, try again..".format(choice)
    else:
        fire_type = 'signal fire'
        try_to_start_fire(fire_type, logs_needed)


def look_for_escape():
    print formatter()
    print "You start walking back the way you think you came." \
          " You walk for what seems like ever and come back to the" \
          " spot that you just left."

    options = ['Find fire wood', 'Cry', 'Find food', 'Build a shelter', 'Build a signal fire',
               'Try to find your way back']

    print "Options are:"

    for i, opt in enumerate(options):
        print "[{}] {}".format(i + 1, opt)  # Print out your possible options at this point

    option = False
    print "\n"
    while option is not True:
        choice = raw_input('What would you like to do, enter a number: ')
        if choice == '1':
            option = True
            gather_fire_wood()
        elif choice == '2':
            option = True
            print die('You start crying loudly. It starts to snow, you have no shelter and freeze.')
        elif choice == '3':
            option = True
            go_hunting()
        elif choice == '4':
            option = True
            build_shelter()
        elif choice == '5':
            option = True
            create_signal_fire()
        elif choice == '6':
            option = True
            look_for_escape()
        else:
            option = False
            print "Expected 1-{} got {}".format(len(options), choice)


def try_to_start_fire(kind_of_fire, logs_needed=5):
    if kind_of_fire == 'signal fire':
        if 'matches' not in BACKPACK or 'fire starter' not in BACKPACK:
            print
```

settings.py:

```
import sys
import time
from choices import rest


BACKPACK = {}  # What you brought
SURVIVAL_TOOLS = {}  # What you'll find
HEALTH = 100


def create_player():
    """Create your character name"""
    player_name = raw_input('Enter your characters name: ').capitalize()
    return player_name


def formatter(width=50):
    """Formatting for to keep everything all pretty
    :type width: Integer"""
    return '*' * width


def die(why):
    """Kill off the program because you did something stupid
    :type why: String"""
    print formatter()
    return "{}. You slowly fade into darkness. Game over.".format(why)


def return_to_camp():
    print formatter()
    print "test"  # TODO: Finish this method


def found_nothing():
    print formatter()
    print "test"  # TODO: Finish this method


def progress_bar():
    """Console based progress bar, nothing to fancy.
    I wanted to do it in color, but couldn't figure out
    how to do it on a Windows machine."""
    for i in range(101):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write("\r[{0}] {1}%".format('#'*(i/10), i))
        sys.stdout.flush()


def eat_food(food):
    if food == 'cooked meat':
        restore(HEALTH, food, 25)
    elif food == 'granola bars':
        restore(HEALTH, food, 5)
    elif food == 'dried foods':
        restore(HEALTH, food, 10)
    else:
        restore(HEALTH, food, -5)


def restore(health, food, amount):
    if amount > 0:
        health += amount
        print "You eat some {} and it makes you feel a bit better.".format(food)
    else:
        health -= amount
        print "You eat some {} and start puking".format(food)
        rest()
```

The rest of the files are in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Ekultek/1a68bfe736a25d1a7541448f72cac620). Would somebody please explain to me exactly what I'm doing wrong? I don't understand why I'm getting an import error if I'm importing from the correct file, is this a simple fix that I'm missing?

Comment: You have circular imports, where `choices` and `settings` both try to import from each other.  Search for questions about circular imports on this site to find discussion of how to restructure your code to deal with this.

Comment: @BrenBarn So if I'm understanding this correctly, I should never import something from a file that also imports something from the file being imported?

Comment: That is a good general policy, yes.  In some cases you can make circular imports work, but usually you can make things work less confusingly by following that rule.

Comment: @BrenBarn Throw it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you. I do have a question though, why is it that you can't do that? I mean where exactly does the program get confused?

Comment: For one thing you mention both gather_firewood AND gather_fire_wood . can you confirm references only point to one function and not another?

Comment: @YoYoYoI'mAwesome: The code is executed top to bottom in each file.  If A does `import B`, then execution of A "waits" while B starts to run.  If B then tries to do `from A import blah`, `blah` is not defined yet because A is still waiting for B to finish before going on to define `blah`.  This is explained in many other questions on this site about circular imports.